# Original function when derivative has sharp turn

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am familiar with why a derivative is undefined where the original function has a sharp turn, but when the derivative has a sharp turn, I don't understand what the original function did that caused such a sharp turn in the derivative. In other words, what does the original function look like for this derivative graphed?

Comment: This would give a discontinuity in the second derivative, so your curvature changes sharply in the original function.

Comment: @RoryDaulton  The graph is possible as is.  It's a graph of the derivative, and the derivative can exist and be continuous and have a corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might think about the difference between the two functions

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2,  & \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
-x^2, & \text{if $x <0$}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x)=x^3.$$

The graphs of both functions are similar.   But the $f'(x)$ has a sharp turn at $x=0,$ while $g'(x)$ does not.   The reason is that $g(x)$ is going to zero much faster than $f(x)$.  So that $g(x)$ is almost flat by the time $x$ gets very close to zero and therefore the curvature of $g(x)$ is $0$ there.
The second derivative makes the transition from negative to positive in a continuous fashion.  So if you imagine the tangent line moving from left to right, when $x<0$, the line is rotating clockwise.  When $x>0$, the line is rotation counter clockwise.  As you move from left to right the clockwise rotation slows, stops and then reverses.

The situation is much different with $f(x)$.  As you move from left to right, the tangent line is rotating clockwise at a certain speed (the second derivative is constant and equal to $-2.$)   At $x=0$, the rotation instantly changes direction (the second derivative is now $2.$)    Anyone riding the tangent line will get whiplash at $x=0.$

A similar thought experiment with the osculating circle might be enlightening.

Comment: I get what you're saying now. However, I still can't think of what the piecewise equation would be roughly for the derivative in the picture.

Comment: actually I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example: the function $f(x)=2|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0.$

If $c$ is a constant, then an anti-derivative $F$ of $f$ is given by

$F(x)=x^2+c$ if $x \ge 0$ and $F(x)=-x^2+c$ if $x < 0$ .

Comment: You do not care, I think.

Comment: @AjayMishra No.  If you mouse over the word "comments" it says "avoid answering questions in the comments."  It says nothing about shortness.